# What is the proper way to perform a join in Meteor?

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a two collections, one has a user_id which references the _id field of a users collection.

I would like to query all the users once and index the array by the _id with the underscore indexBy function, then display the user name in a table instead of the user_id

Something like this:

```
Template.posts.users_by_id = function() {
    _.indexBy(Users.find().fetch(), '_id');
}
```

In the template:

```
{{ users_by_id[user_id].name }}
```

However, the users_by_id gets called for every row in the table instead of once.  I've tried store the result of `_.indexBy` in `Template.posts.user_by_id` but then I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Users is not defined`

Also, I can't seem to access the name key and only `[object Object]` is shown.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to optimize performance... but you're still using autopublish?

If it were me, I'd subscribe to the Users collection with the user_ids you want and have the server publish that collection back to the client. Since those Users are then effectively in local memory, calling Users.find(user_id).fetch().name should take very little time. And it's also reactive, so when your collection updates, your interface will too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store users in a dictionary, you'll need a dictionary!

```
var users = {};
// var usersDep = new Deps.Dependency();

Template.posts.created = function() {
  users = _.indexBy(Users.find().fetch(), '_id');
  // usersDep.changed();
};

Template.posts.users_by_id = function() {
  // usersDep.depend();
  return users;
};
```

I've added dependency management in the comments. Depending on where you initialize the dictionary it might or might not be necessary, I'm not sure right now.

Notice that you can simplify the helper by returning just the user instead of the whole dictionary:

```
Template.posts.user_by_id = function() {
  return users[this.user_id];
};
```

---

Given that all user object you've subscribed to are already in the quite effective Minimongo, I'd suggest the direct approach:

```
Template.posts.user_name = function() {
  return Users.findOne(this.user_id).name;
};
```

On one hand you've got a Minimongo lookup instead of plain object lookup, but on the other you don't need the additional memory for the dictionary, you don't need the time to fill and index it, and you won't run into problems with reactivity. If optimization in this place is crucial for your application, try both approaches and compare their rendering times.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical join pattern with Meteor. Perform the join using a query.

```
<template name="users">
  {{#each users}}
    {{> user}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="user">
  {{#with user}}
    {{name}}
  {{/with}}
</template>

Template.users.helpers({
  users: function() {
    SomeCollection.find();
  }
});

Template.user.helpers({
  user: function() {
    return Users.findOne(this.user_id);
  }
});
```